# Tuple of 2 Int and contain method in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tuples

Trying to make a list tuple of two Integers and after that adding something in it. Then comparing if x,y is one of the tuples in list tuple.

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> monsterPositions;
```

I instantly get error like this that it doesn't have Tuple:

> Assets/TimeMap.cs(20,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Tuple' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I found out that I can add inside tuple like this:

```
monsterPositions.Add(randomX, randomY);
```

Then the hardest part is how can I compare the x and y in my Tuple list. I am trying to use `Contains` but I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
monsterPositions.Contains(Tuple(x, y));
```

Comment: do you have `using System;` at top of your cs file?

Comment: I have using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

Comment: then add `using System;`, its needed for Tuple.

Comment: Unity [does not support](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/381993/does-unity-4-mono-support-tuples.html) `Tuples`.

Comment: @S.Akbari What do you suggest to use then?

Comment: Why not use your own class or struct, implementing equality appropriately? That would be cleaner to use anyway, as then you'd have appropriate `X` and `Y` properties instead of just `Item1` and `Item2`.

Answer (score 7):

Pulling out @S.Akbari's comment on the question as I almost missed it when looking through:

> Unity [does not support](https://answers.unity.com/questions/381993/does-unity-4-mono-support-tuples.html) `Tuples`.

Still the case in Unity 2017.3.1f1.

Other observations:

- You can use `Vector2` or `Vector2Int` (and the other numbers) if you're just storing `float`s and `int`s.
- I noticed that UniRx has `Tuple` support, if you're using that o.O
- Best follow @Jon Skeet's advice and make your own class or struct otherwise, or like he mentioned, to implement equality if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ancient post, but in aid of those who may stumble upon it, as of 2020 Unity C# supports built-in tuple construction in a new way.

If you don't need the small overhead of Vector2Int, you can use the following declaration:

```
private (int,int) monsterPositions = (randomX,randomY); //assuming <T>randomX,Y == int
```

These int tuples can be stored as coordinate pairs in arrays or hashSets, and can be accessed with simple search or .Contains functions

Answer (score 2):

Change the player settings "API compatibility level" to ".NET 4.x":

[image: Change API compatibility level to .NET 4.x]